# Can someone tell me how to fix this memory format for malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc, cs50

I'm trying to allocate memory for an array in C and I'm getting an error. No idea what's wrong, here. The error is yelling at me regarding pBuffer.

```
//Allocate memory
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
int *BLOCK_MEM = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);
int buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
int *pBuffer = &buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
pBuffer = &BLOCK_MEM;
```

Even if this were right, would I still be able to use the array as normal, or would I have a bunch of issues?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Both the initialization of `pBuffer` and the assignment on the next line seems very odd. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also note that `&BLOCK_MEM` will have the type `int **`. That's not the type of `pBuffer`.

Comment: And please [don't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: `int *pBuffer = buffer;` which is equivalent to `int *pBuffer = &buffer[0];` @h0r53

Comment: Don't use `ALL_CAPS` names for variables. This is conventionally used for macros.

Comment: Be consistent — sometimes you use `512`, sometimes you use `BLOCK_SIZE`; use `BLOCK_SIZE` everywhere except where you initialize it.

Comment: @h0r53: I think you mean `int *pBuffer = buffer;`, do you not?

Comment: `int *pBuffer = &buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];` will initialize `pBuffer` to point just past the last element of `buffer[];`. If you want it to point to the first element of `buffer[]`, initialize it as `int *pBuffer = buffer;` or `int *pBuffer = &buffer[0];`. `pBuffer = &BLOCK_MEM;` makes no sense as it is the wrong type. To make `pBuffer` point to the first `int` in the allocated memory pointed to by `BLOCK_MEM`, use `pBuffer = BLOCK_MEM;` or `pBuffer = &BLOCK_MEM[0];`.

Comment: What are you trying to do???

Comment: OK, so you have an actual array (`buffer`), and you have a dynamically allocated block of memory (pointed to by `BLOCK_MEM` if the `malloc` call returned a non-null value) that can be indexed like an array, and you have a pointer that can point to any integer and that can be indexed like an array if those indexed elements are contained within (or just past the end of) an array or within (or just past the end of) a dynamically allocated block of memory, or if the pointer is pointing to a non-array `int` and the index is 0 or 1 (and not accessing past the end). But what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
int *BLOCK_MEM = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 512);
```

Here you define a named constant with value 512 but then use a literal `512`. If these are supposed to be the same thing, use the named constant. If they are supposed to be different, define a second named constant and add a comment explaining why two different values are needed.

In C, unlike C++, it is not recommended to cast a call to `malloc` because it can suppress certain error messages. Also, it is recommended to use `sizeof *p`, where `p` is the pointer being assigned or initialized, instead of `sizeof (type)`, because the former automatically adapts if the type of `p` is later changed, whereas the latter requires that the type be changed in two places. (So it is less work to change the former and less likely a human will mistakenly miss the fact they need to make the change in multiple places.)

So that line would become `int *BLOCK_MEM = malloc(sizeof *BLOCK_MEM * BLOCK_SIZE);`.

```
int *pBuffer = &buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];
```

This initializes `pBuffer` to point to end of `buffer`, specifically to a place one beyond the last element of `pBuffer`. That is probably not what you want to do. To initialize `pBuffer` to point to the start of buffer, you could use `int *pBuffer = &buffer[0];`. However, you could also use `int *pBuffer = buffer;`, because the array `buffer` will automatically be converted to a pointer to its first element when used this way.

```
pBuffer = &BLOCK_MEM;
```

This does not make sense with the previous line. `int *pBuffer = &buffer[BLOCK_SIZE];` initializes `pBuffer` and then `pBuffer = &BLOCK_MEM;` immediately changes it, so the initialization had no effect. You should simply initialize `pBuffer` to the value you want it to have. And, if `pBuffer` is going to point to the allocated memory, you do not need to define `buffer` at all, unless you need it for some other purpose.

Additionally, the types are wrong in this assignment. `BLOCK_MEM` is a pointer to `int`, so `&BLOCK_MEM` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int` (type `int **`). But `pBuffer` is a pointer to an `int` (type `int *`). So the compiler issues a message that this assignment has a problem.

To set `pBuffer` to point to where `BLOCK_MEM` points, use `pBuffer = BLOCK_MEM;`.

Comment: I think OP needs to read pointer & array chapters in his book first.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is

```c
const int BLOCK_SIZE = 512;

int *pBuffer = malloc( sizeof( int ) * BLOCK_SIZE );
```

Well, not quite. You might want to check the result of `malloc` to make sure it's not `NULL`.

```c
if ( !pBuffer ) {
   perrror( "malloc" );
   exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

---

> I still be able to use the array as normal

Well, you have a pointer, not an array. But virtually every time you use an array, it degrades into a pointer to its first element. (For example, `a[4]` ⇒ `*( a + 4 )` ⇒ `*( &a[0] + 4 )`). So yeah, you can use the pointer as an array. (Meaning `p[4]` will work just as well.) `sizeof` is the notable exception.